# how to remove all listeners in GeoQuery

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am working on location app for something like uber, I am searching for a driver in a nearby location with a particular radius, after that I call GeoQuery.removeAllListeners to remove that data but I am still having some duplicate data in my firebase. I don't know why it's.

Here is my code:

```
private GeoQuery geoQuery;

private void getTheClosestDriver() {
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(driverAvailableRef);
    geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(customerPickUpLocation.latitude,customerPickUpLocation.longitude),radius);
    geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            if (!driverFound && requestType){
                driverFound = true;
                driverFoundID = key;

                driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Drivers").child(driverFoundID);

                HashMap driverMap = new HashMap();
                driverMap.put("customerFoundId",customerID);
                driverRef.updateChildren(driverMap);
                
                gettingTheDriverLocation();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
            if (!driverFound){
                radius = radius + 1;

                getTheClosestDriver();
                bookARide.setText("Searching For a Driver Location");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(CustomerMapsActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is "some duplicate data" that is showing up in your database? Can you show us that JSON (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). --- I'd also recommend setting a breakpoint inside `onKeyEntered` and `onGeoQueryReady`, running in the debugger, and stepping through it line by line, looking at each variable, and telling us what you find that way.

Comment: The issue is that the database supposed to be created when I login as a driver only, that's from the driver map activity, but the issue is that if I login as a passenger at the first time(note this is from another activity entirely), it won't create the other database but when I logout and probable login as a driver, it will create the database in which that's what I needed but if I logout as the driver and then login as a user again, it will use the user unique key as a driver, which probable means that the removeAllListener is not working because it supposed not to be so